# Since for prime $p$, $p^2-1$ is divisible by $8,$ $x^{p^2-1}-1$ is divisible by $x^8-1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I was reading Dummit and Foote, and in there, there is a line that goes like this:

> Since for prime $p$, $p^2-1$ is divisible by $8,$ $x^{p^2-1}-1$ is divisible by $x^8-1$.

I get that $p^2-1$ is divisible by $8.$ But how does that fact imply that $x^{p^2-1}-1$ is divisible by $x^8-1$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove：$x^d-1 \mid x^n-1$ iff $d \mid n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462569/prove-xd-1-mid-xn-1-iff-d-mid-n) See also e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3889183 or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/609900 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $$p^2-1=8k$$ then

$$x^{p^2-1}-1=x^{8k}-1$$

Let $y=x^8$, we have $y^k-1=(y-1)\sum_{r=0}^{k-1}y^r$.   That is $y-1$ divides $y^k-1$.

That is $x^8-1$ dividis $x^{8k}-1=x^{p^2-1}-1$.

Comment: Please don't duplicate answers to such FAQ's.

Answer (score 2):

$$x^{ab}-1=(x^a-1)(x^{a(b-1)}+x^{a(b-2)}+x^{a(b-3)}+\cdots+x^{a}+x^0)$$

Comment: Please don't duplicate answers to such FAQ's.