# Show that if $x^d -1$ divides $x^n -1$ if and only if $d$ divides $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, arithmetic, divisibility

I have done one part. If $d$ divides $n$ then $n=dp$ for some $p$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.
Then $x^n -1=x^{dp} -1$. Then $x^d -1$ is a factor of $x^n-1$. So $x^d -1$ divides $x^n -1$.

But how to show reverse part?

Comment: This has been asked and answered here lots and lots of times, e.g. [Prove：$x^d-1 \mid x^n-1$ iff $d \mid n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462569/prove-xd-1-mid-xn-1-iff-d-mid-n)